# Is there any detailed doc or sample codes about PBFSCopyFileSync from CoreService framework?

Tags: cocoa, api, macos

I am trying to replace the deprecated API `PBHCopyFileSync` with `PBFSCopyFileSync` as recommend in `Files.h` header.

Surprisingly, Apple only says several lines for this new API:

```
PBFSCopyFileSync
Duplicates a file and optionally renames it.

OSStatus PBFSCopyFileSync (
   FSRefParamPtr paramBlock
);
Availability
Available in Mac OS X v10.5 and later.
Declared In
Files.h
```

And I couldn't find more about how to use this function.

Specially, what should be filled into the parameter `FSRefParamPtr`? I tried code below, but keeps getting an error of -50.

```
paramErr     -50    
Invalid value passed in a parameter. Your application
passed an invalid parameter for dialog options.
```

Here is the code:

```
OSStatus res = noErr;

FSRefParam param;

FSRef srcFile, dstDir, newFile;

const char *src = "$PATH_TO_A_EXISTING_FILE";
const char *dst = "/tmp";

res = FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)src, &srcFile, NULL);
assert(res == noErr);

res = FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)dst, &dstDir, NULL);
assert(res == noErr);

memset(&param, 0, sizeof(FSRefParam));
param.ioCompletion = NULL;
param.ref = &srcFile;
param.parentRef = &dstDir;
param.newRef = &newFile;

res = PBFSCopyFileSync(&param);

if (res == noErr) {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
} else {
    printf("FAILED!!! %d\n", res);
}
```

So, does anyone know some detailed documentation or sample codes about this API? Or is there any more popular/documented C++ API for copying files?

Thanks.

Comment: Still cannot find doc on PBFSCopyFileSync. But found `FSCopyObjectSync`, which is better documented, and decided to use it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quinn “The Eskimo!” says:](http://lists.apple.com/archives/filesystem-dev/2008/Apr/msg00038.html)

> Always use FSCopyObjectSync. PBFSCopyFileSync/PBHCopyFileSync are low-level routines that are exported for legacy reasons. FSCopyObjectSync is a proper API that takes care of all of the nittygritty details of copying.
>
> Notably, both PBFSCopyFileSync and PBHCopyFileSync are parameter block routines, with no nice wrappers. You should consider that a hint (-: